# Is it possible to get an IQueryable<> back from an EF set when you apply a predicate?

Tags: c#, predicates

It appears to return IEnumerable rather than IQueryable:

method parameter: `Func<Cat, bool> predicate`

code:

```
var allCats = _catEntities.GetCats(); // IQueryable

if (skip.HasValue) allCats = allCats .Skip(skip.Value);
if (take.HasValue) allCats = allCats .Take(take.Value);

 if (predicate != null)
            {
                allCats = allCats.Where(predicate);
            }
```

This doesn't compile because `.Where` returns `IEnumerable` instead of `IQueryable`. I know I can do `.AsQueryable` or whatever but I suspect that won't treat it as a proper `IQueryable`.

Is there a simple fix for this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that `Func<Cat, bool>` is already compiled as .NET code, and as such it cannot be executed outside of the .NET process.

So, in order to apply the predicate to `allCats`, the query defined by `allCats` at that time will have to be executed. Using `AsQueryable` would, as you surmise, only wrap the returned `IEnumerable` enumeration.

If you want the predicate to be translated and executed by the LINQ provider, you can use an `Expression<Func<Cat, bool>>`. Note that that will introduce a coupling between the `IQueryable` implementation and the definition of the predicate. (Because the predicate must be something that can be executed by the LINQ provider).

Using a lambda-expression, it is possible to define an `Expression<Func<Cat, bool>>` pretty simply:

```
Expression<Func<Cat, bool>> predicateExpression = c => c.Gender == Gender.Male;
```

Comment: Interesting, thanks. How does it precompile it considering it's passed in as a parameter though? It could be one of many different things. Fixed it though, thanks.

Comment: There are two (big) steps. The C# compiler will transform the lambda-expression into an expression tree (i.e. an [Abstract Syntax Tree](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abstract_syntax_tree)). Then the LINQ provider processes the expression tree and transforms it into a form that it can execute (in EF's case, SQL code).

Answer (score 2):

That `predicate` parameter should be an `Expression<Func<Cat, bool>>`, not just a `Func<Cat, bool>`.

That way you *will* get an IQueryable back, because you will use the [Queryable.Where](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb535040.ASPX) instead of Enumerable.Where.

You can still use a lambda expression when you call your method: the compiler knows how to translate a lambda into an Expression.